# AssetForURL returns nil

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to use AssetForURL method but it is returning nil.

This is the code i'm using:

```
-(void)addAssetURL:(NSURL*)assetURL toAlbum:(NSString*)albumName withCompletionBlock:(SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock
{
__block BOOL albumWasFound = NO;

//search all photo albums in the library
[self enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum 
                    usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

                        //compare the names of the albums
                        if ([albumName compare: [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]]==NSOrderedSame) {

                            //target album is found
                            albumWasFound = YES;

                            //get a hold of the photo's asset instance
                            [self assetForURL: assetURL
                                  resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                      //add photo to the target album
                                      [group addAsset: asset];
                                      //run the completion block
                                      completionBlock(nil);

                                  } failureBlock: completionBlock];

                            //album was found, bail out of the method
                            return;
                        }

                        if (group==nil && albumWasFound==NO) {
                            //photo albums are over, target album does not exist, thus create it

                            __weak ALAssetsLibrary* weakSelf = self;

                            //create new assets album
                            [self addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:albumName 
                                                  resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {

                                                      //get the photo's instance
                                                      [weakSelf assetForURL: assetURL 
                                                                    resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

                                                                        //add photo to the newly created album
                                                                        [group addAsset: asset];

                                                                        //call the completion block
                                                                        completionBlock(nil);

                                                                    } failureBlock: completionBlock];

                                                  } failureBlock: completionBlock];

                            //should be the last iteration anyway, but just in case
                            return;
                        }

                    } failureBlock: completionBlock];

}
```

The url i'm giving it is:

```
    file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/6630FBD3-1212-4ED0-BC3B-0C23AEEFB267/tmp/capture-T0x1d56e310.tmp.N3SZXy/capturedvideo.MOV
```

I'm getting the URL from the camera delegate method:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSLog(@"%@",[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]);

    [library addAssetURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] toAlbum:@"Compedia videos" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you can access the url? Try it in the browser of the device/simulator.

Comment: `assetForURL` has no return type (void). Do you mean that the asset in the resultBlock is nil?

Comment: Yes, this is what i meant

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, @user2328703 have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have access to assets library?
Don't forget to check access status

```
ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
if (status == ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
    __block BOOL accessChecked = NO; /// *stop is not respected immediately
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (accessChecked) return ;
        *stop = YES;
        accessChecked = YES;
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
    }];
}
else {
    BOOL granted = status == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized;
}
```

---

```
- (void)enumerateGroupsWithTypes:(ALAssetsGroupType)types usingBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock)enumerationBlock failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock
```

> Description    Invokes a given block passing as a parameter each of the
> asset groups that match the given asset group type. The results are
> passed one by one to the caller by executing the enumeration block.
> This method is asynchronous. When groups are enumerated, the user may
> be asked to confirm the application's access to the data; the method,
> though, returns immediately. You should perform whatever work you want
> with the assets in enumerationBlock.
>
> If the user denies access to the
> application, or if no application is allowed to access the data, the
> failureBlock is called.